# Rookie Question: Regex in ZSH Script

Tags: zsh, regular-expression, string

I think my problem is very simple. I want to construct a new filename, which has a fixed prefix and a number (two digits), which is part of the old filename.

Example: I have a file 'blableblub23.pdf' and I want to move it by renaming it to 'Newfile 23', where 'Newfile' is the fixed prefix.

So, first I have to get rid of all not-numbers in the old filename, and that is my main problem. I am trying with

```
paperno=expr match "$filename" '.*([0-9][0-9]).*'
filename_new="Newfile $paperno"
```

I always got filename_new = "Newfile" with no number, but I am expecting "Newfile 23".

Where is my fault?

Thank you very, very much ;)

Edit for clarification:

I have a filename (stored in $filename) which contains a number of two digits anywhere in the filename, i. e.

Test_bla_blub_23_and_more.pdf
Test_23.pdf
Test_23_bla.pdf

I just want to store the numbers (in examples: 23) in another variable $paperno to compose a new filename.

If there are no numbers in the filename or more than one numbers, the variable $paperno should be empty or 0. If there are more than one numbers, I also would accept if I get a return of all numbers. I.E.:

Test_12_bla_blub_23_and_more.pdf
=> $paperno = 1223

Sorry, I'm very new to shell scripts, zsh and regular expressions....

Answer (score 2):

`zsh` has some builtin support for regexp matching (both ERE and PCRE), it also has extended glob operators that go beyond regexps. No need to use that antiquated and broken by design `expr` command (which uses BREs, *Basic* regular expressions itself).

It even has a batch renaming tool:

```
autoload -Uz zmv
zmv -v '(*[^0-9]|)(<->).pdf' 'Newfile $1'
```

`(*)(<->).pdf`, like `.*([0-9][0-9])\.pdf` wouldn't work because in `foo1234.pdf` for instance, the `*` (resp. `.*`) would match `foo123` (resp. `foo12`) leaving only the minimum possible (`4`) for `<->`. (resp. `34` for `[0-9][0-9]`).

If using PCREs, you'd be able to use non-greedy matching operators, as with:

```
set -o rematchpcre
[[ $file =~ '^.*?(\d+)\.pdf\z' ]]
number=$match[1]
```

Though, here you don't need the `.*` if you don't anchor the regexp at the start (with `^` above, `expr` anchors at the start implicitly):

```
[[ $file =~ '(\d+)\.pdf$' ]]
```

(`$` for EREs, the default, `\z` with PCRE, after `set -o rematchpcre`).

Alternatively here, you could also do:

```
zmv '*<->.pdf' 'Newfile ${(M)${f:r}%%<->}'
```

Where `${f:r}` expands to the *root name* (extension removed) of the file, and `${(M)param%%pattern}` expands to the longest tail of the param that matches the `pattern` (here `<->` matching any sequence of ASCII decimal numbers, `<x-y>` without bound).

To extract all the digits from the file name, for instance for `foo-123-bar.pdf` to be renamed to `Newfile 123` or `foo1bar2.pdf` to be renamed to `Newfile 12`:

```
zmv -v '*[0-9]*.pdf' 'Newfile ${f//[^0-9]}'
```

Where `${f//pattern/replacement}` expands to `$f` with all the occurrences `pattern` replaced with `replacement`. The replacement here is omitted, so we replace all characters other than decimal digits with nothing.

For completeness, to extract the list of digits before the `.pdf`, with `expr`, you'd do:

```
number=$(expr "x$file" : '.*[^0123456789]\([0123456789]\{1,\}\)\.pdf$')
```

Bearing in mind that it will return a failure exit status if that number is not found but also if it's `0` or `00`, `000`...

The `x` prefix is to work around `expr`'s design bugs whereby if the expansion of `$file` happened to be a `expr` operator, it would be taken as such.

Note that `match` is not a standard `expr` operator, the standard equivalent is with that `:` operator.

Again, `expr` is a very broken and limited utility from the 70s, there is no good reason to keep using it in this day and age, especially in `zsh` which has very powerful text extraction and formatting functionality built in.

Comment: You are right, i tried my regex regex101 and it turned out, that I get rid of all not-number-characters with '[0-9][0-9]'. 

paperno=expr match "$filename" '[0-9][0-9]'
filename_new="RLS Aktuell neu $paperno"

makes me an empty variable 'paperno' and I don't know, why....

Comment: @Ralf, `paperno=expr match "$filename" '[0-9][0-9]'` tries to invoke the `match` command with `paperno=expr` in its environment. The syntax to get the output of a command into a variable is `var=$(cmd)`

Comment: I understand you correctly, using this? 
paperno=$(expr match "$filename" '[0-9][0-9]')
filename_new="RLS Aktuell neu $paperno"
Unfortunately this has the same result - no number after "neu"

Comment: @Ralf, please read my answer where I gave the correct syntax.

Comment: I did so, but it's hard to understand for a Rookie. Your expression number=$(expr "x$file" : .... returns an empty field with $file = "Test_file_45_bla.pdf". What I want, is to get the "45" to compose a new filename with it.

Comment: @Ralf, in your question, you have the number before `.pdf`. If the number can be anywhere in the file name, please edit your question to clarify so. Also clarify what to do if the file name contains more than one sequence of decimal digits

Comment: I did (see "edit" in original posting).

Comment: Thanks. Then see the `zmv -v '*[0-9]*.pdf' 'Newfile ${f//[^0-9]}'` in my answer (or `paperno=${filename//[^0-9]}`

Comment: worx! Thank you very much, you saved my day!

Answer (score 0):

**expr output** is the number of characters that matched, did you try printing paperno variable ? I don't think it gives you the spected output

- https://www.computerhope.com/unix/uexpr.htm

May be the approach is to strip all strings and then cut by ".", then you have your number. like:

```
charstostrip=expr match "$filename" '^[a-zA-Z]+$'
modified=${$filename:$charstostrip}
fn_number=${echo $modified | cut -d . -f1}
filename_new="Newfile $fn_number"
```

Comment: The problem is, that I am writing a Shell Script in Apple Automator, so I could not use 'echo'. But also with my new regex '[0-9][0-9]' which is correct (according to regex101) my variable 'paperno' is empty and I don't know why.

Comment: The approach is: Get rid of all non-number-characters and get just the numbers in $filename into another variable $paperno. Example: filename = "Test_file_45_bla.pdf" => paperno = "45"